# Labeling internet traffic traces from .pcap file and saving in .csv format

Tags: csv, pcap, packets, network-traffic, labeling

I have internet traffic traces in form of .pcap file. I want to label the packets in those traces depending upon whether they belong to HTTP, FTP, DNS, P2P, SMTP, etc and save the results as .csv file. I have heard about the DPI tools called L7-filter and the likes but could not find how to work with them and also don't know if they could do this job of labeling. I want to use these labeled records in training machine-learning classifiers. Can anyone help me by providing solution in detail?
Please provide any alternative method (if useful).

Comment: My [Pcap4J](https://www.pcap4j.org/) can do it if you write Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but will Pcap4J be able to label packets or flows as belonging to applications like HTTP, FTP, DNS, P2P, SMTP, etc. since I have offline .pcap traces and I want to label them for training the ML classifiers?

Comment: You can write code to find which packet is which protocol by Pcap4J. Then you can label them in your way.